# Calculating weightedMedian (matrixStats) coloumnwise by category

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, median

Let's assume I have two dataframes "values" and "weights" and I would like to calculate weighted medians coloumnwise (year1, year2) by category (A, B, C) :

```
values <- data.frame(TICKER=c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"), year1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), year2=c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
weights <- data.frame(TICKER=c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"), year1=c(0.3,0.7,0.25,0.25,0.5,0.1,0.1,0.6,0.2), year2=c(0.6,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.3))
```

For this purpose I wanted to use ddply and the weightedMedian function (package matrixStats).

```
output <- ddply(values, .(TICKER), colwise(weightedMedian(values, weights), na.rm=TRUE))
```

However, I get the error message:

```
"(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"
```

Does anybody know how to adjust the code to get a solution that works?

I tried to transform the dataframes to matrices (via as.matrix), as weightedMedian requires a matrix as input. However, this doesn't help. 
The only solution I found so far is a loop using subsetting (however, this is extremely slow and not very elegant)

```
output <- matrix(data=0, nrow=3, ncol=2)
for (i in 2:ncol(values)){
 for (j in 1:length(unique(values$TICKER))){
  values.j <- subset(values, values$TICKER == as.character(unique(values$TICKER)[j]))
  weights.j <-  subset(weights, weights$TICKER == as.character(unique(values$TICKER)[j]))
  output[j,(i-1)] <- weightedMedian(values.j[,i], weights.j[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi - no, the real data contains ca. 70 periods (coloumns) and approx ca. 15,000 categories

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `weightedMedian` function mentioned by the OP, the `Hmisc` package supplies a more general `wtd.quantile` function.

I split both data.frames into lists and the apply these functions to both year variables with nested `sapply`s. Comparing the results below, it appears that the `weightedMedian` produces the desired result.

To prepare the data, split the values and the weights into lists along their TICKER.

```
# split values and weights into lists by category
valuesList <- split(values, values$TICKER)
weightsList <- split(weights, values$TICKER)
```

---

If I use `weightedMedian` from the OP's question in the above code, I get the following:

```
library(matrixStats)
sapply(names(valuesList),
  function(i) sapply(names(valuesList[[i]])[-1],
                function(j) weightedMedian(valuesList[[i]][[j]],
                                           w=weightsList[[i]][[j]])))

        A        B C
year1 1.7 4.333333 8
year2 8.6 6.125000 3
```

---

Another package, `Hmisc`, has a weighted quantile function, `wtd.quantile`.

```
# load Hmisc package
library(Hmisc)

sapply(names(valuesList),
   function(i) sapply(names(valuesList[[i]])[-1],
                   function(j) {
                     wtd.quantile(valuesList[[i]][[j]],
                                  weights=weightsList[[i]][[j]], probs=0.5)}))
```

This returns

```
myMedians 
          A B C
year1.50% 2 5 9
year2.50% 9 7 4
```

From inspection, the results from `matrixStats` appear more reasonable. For example,  TICKER==C, year==2 should not be 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to stay in the plyr/weightedStats context, I would first combine both `data.frames` and then run `ldply` in conjunction with `ddply` using the known column indices of your value variables:

```
df <- data.frame(values,wt=weights)

output <- lapply(names(values)[-1], 
   function(i) ddply(df,.(TICKER), 
     function(x) setNames(weightedMedian(x=x[,i],w=x[,match(i,names(x))+ncol(x)/2]),i)))
```

Then you can do the following to get the result into a single data.frame

```
do.call('join',output)
```

which gives you

```
  TICKER    year1 year2
1      A 1.700000 8.600
2      B 4.333333 6.125
3      C 8.000000 3.000
```

By the way, the reason for your error message is that you only 'slice' your `values` data.frame while you are calling your entire `weights` data.frame in `weightedMedian`.